# Is there a g++ warning for static pointer to local variable?

Tags: c++, g++, warnings, compiler-warnings

I've seen an interesting bug in code of this form:

```
#include <iostream>

char * some_function(void)
{
    char local_string[] = "Hello, world!";
    static char * static_pointer = local_string;    // Here is the bug

    std::cout << static_pointer << std::endl;

    return local_string;    // Here is a related bug
}

void function_nest(void)
{
    int i = 5;
    // std::cout << i << std::endl;
    some_function();
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    some_function();
    function_nest();
    some_function();
}
```

The first time this function is called, then the value of `*static_pointer` is well-defined (it's a pointer to "Hello, world!"). But on subsequent calls, the pointer is meaningless because it was pointing to a local variable (on the stack presumably) of the first call.

If I compile with `g++`, then it gives me a warning for the return, as I'd expect:

```
static-pointer-bug2.cpp:6:10: warning: address of local variable ‘local_string’ returned [enabled by default]
```

But it doesn't give any warning for `static_pointer` being initialised with `local_string`. It's the same category of bug.

When I run it (Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit Intel PC) I get:

```
Hello, world!
�ˤ��
Hello, world!
```

(I guess I get lucky the 3rd time.)

Is there any `g++` warning that can be enabled to catch this?

Comment: `-Waddress` is the only one I found that *might* do that. Your third function call got "lucky" because you called the same function a second time from main, so the stackframe of `some_function`, including the vairable `local_string` got allocated at the same location as the first time.

Comment: `-Waddress` didn't do it when I just tried it with g++ version `g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3`.